# jQuery onClick uses first button only

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have this jQuery

```
$("#rfidbutton").click(function() {
 var rfid = $(this).data('rfidnumber');
 $(".modal-body #rfidbox").val( rfid );
 $("#rfidtitle").text( 'Save RFID - ' + rfid );
 Cookies.set("rfid=" + rfid);
 //Cookies.get("rfid");
});
```

The buttons look like this

```
<a class="btn btn-tertiary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" href="#rfid" data-rfidnumber="1" id="rfidbutton"><i class="fa fa-id-card-o"></i> Click here</a>
<a class="btn btn-tertiary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" href="#rfid" data-rfidnumber="2" id="rfidbutton"><i class="fa fa-id-card-o"></i> Click here</a>
<a class="btn btn-tertiary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" href="#rfid" data-rfidnumber="3" id="rfidbutton"><i class="fa fa-id-card-o"></i> Click here</a>
<a class="btn btn-tertiary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" href="#rfid" data-rfidnumber="4" id="rfidbutton"><i class="fa fa-id-card-o"></i> Click here</a>
```

The problem is that when a button is clicked, '1' is always saved into the cookie.
How do I get the data-rfidnumber of the *clicked* button, not the first one?

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Comment: Id must be a good unique, use class name instead

Answer (score 5):

Elements should not have the same id `#rfidbutton` use a class instead `.rfidbutton`.

```
<a class="btn btn-tertiary btn-xs rfidbutton" data-toggle="modal" href="#rfid" data-rfidnumber="1"><i class="fa fa-id-card-o"></i> Click here</a>
<a class="btn btn-tertiary btn-xs rfidbutton" data-toggle="modal" href="#rfid" data-rfidnumber="2"><i class="fa fa-id-card-o"></i> Click here</a>
<a class="btn btn-tertiary btn-xs rfidbutton" data-toggle="modal" href="#rfid" data-rfidnumber="3"><i class="fa fa-id-card-o"></i> Click here</a>
<a class="btn btn-tertiary btn-xs rfidbutton" data-toggle="modal" href="#rfid" data-rfidnumber="4"><i class="fa fa-id-card-o"></i> Click here</a>
```

And the js...

```
$(".rfidbutton").click(function() {
 var rfid = $(this).data('rfidnumber');
 $(".modal-body #rfidbox").val( rfid );
 $("#rfidtitle").text( 'Uložit RFID - ' + rfid );
 Cookies.set("rfid=" + rfid);
 //Cookies.get("rfid");
});
```

ID's should be unique, jQuery is just returning the first element with the ID you asked for. If you use the class selector it will return all elements with that class.

I would suggest reading up on [jQuery selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), you could even select by an arbitrary attribute like your `data-rfidnumber` if you wanted. So any element that has the `data-rfidnumber` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

ID is unique for the whole document.Better change the selector with className

```js
$(".btn-xs").click(function() {
  var rfid = $(this).data('rfidnumber');
  $(".modal-body #rfidbox").val(rfid);
  $("#rfidtitle").text('Uložit RFID - ' + rfid);
  console.log(rfid)
  //Cookies.set("rfid=" + rfid);
  //Cookies.get("rfid");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn btn-tertiary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" href="#rfid" data-rfidnumber="1" id="rfidbutton"><i class="fa fa-id-card-o"></i> Click here</a>
<a class="btn btn-tertiary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" href="#rfid" data-rfidnumber="2" id="rfidbutton"><i class="fa fa-id-card-o"></i> Click here</a>
<a class="btn btn-tertiary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" href="#rfid" data-rfidnumber="3" id="rfidbutton"><i class="fa fa-id-card-o"></i> Click here</a>
<a class="btn btn-tertiary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" href="#rfid" data-rfidnumber="4" id="rfidbutton"><i class="fa fa-id-card-o"></i> Click here</a>
```

Comment: While this would work, it would also use any other btn-xs classed elements (not obvious from my question). But thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use ID for multiple elements.  Use one of your classes instead, for example:

```
$(".btn-tertiary").click(function() {
 // Same click function callback
});
```